# 3D Model Map Android App Integration

Tags: android, 3d, maps, integration

We are making an Android App that has a `Map` Feature of our Campus.

Just for our campus only.

The integration to Android seems to be not a problem, but I need an advise regarding the `maps`.

In case we got the sketch of `(2d)map` is there any tool so we can model it to `3D` View? Then integrate the map to the android app.

We will have functions like `Shortest Path`, `Zoom-in`, `Zoom-out`, `Rotate`.

Just an advice how we can make a 3D model from a sketch or tools or techniques.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively easy 3D tool.
http://www.sketchup.com/

However, you'll still need import it into your app. Then you'll need to parse that file and create vertices, faces, import textures and materials.

Depending on the size of your generated model, Java will most likely be too slow to handle 3D rendering in OpenGL. You will need to utilize the Android-NDK. This will require that you utilize C or C++ and interface with it using Java Native Interface (JNI).

The above is to only get your model to render. You will then need to insert the features you have listed in your initial question. The rotation feature will require you to render it multiple times per second (I generally use 30 as a benchmark).

This is not a trivial task, but it certainly sounds fun.
Good luck